# Get data from clicked elements Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, click

I have a page where User can select people to add in his team.
One side of the page is the list of the people to select.
When user click Add to the team, it goes to the right side where we have the list of the selected people.

I don't understand how I can get the data on the selected side from the view in django..

For example on the left:

```
<div class="card-body" id="team-list">                   
   <p class="card-text">Select today's teammates:</p>
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      {% for tech in techs %}
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="name" name="{{tech.id}}">{{tech.name}}</span>
            <span class="move" style="float: right;">Add to the team</span>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

and on the right:

```
<div class="card-body" id="selected-list">
  <h3 class="title">You have selected the following teammates for today: </h3>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="list-style-type: none;">

  </ul>
</div>
```

The click is handled by a little js click event like this:

```
    var selected = document.querySelector('#selected-list ul');
    var team = document.querySelector('#team-list ul');
function clickHandlerTeam(e){


        if(e.target.classList.contains('move')){
            if (e.target.textContent == 'Add to the team'){
                console.log('changing add');
                e.target.textContent ='Remove from the team';
                selected.appendChild(e.target.parentNode);
            } else {
                console.log('changing remove');
                e.target.textContent = 'Add to the team';
                team.appendChild(e.target.parentNode);
            }    

        console.log('****************');

        }
        return;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ selected_techs=[] }}
<div class="card-body" id="team-list">                   
   <p class="card-text">Select today's teammates:</p>
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      {% for tech in techs %}
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="name" name="{{tech.id}}">{{tech.name}}</span>
            <span class="move" onclick="{{ selected_techs.append(tech) }}" style="float: right;">Add to the team</span>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div class="card-body" id="selected-list">
  <h3 class="title">You have selected the following teammates for today: </h3>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="list-style-type: none;">
      {% for tech in selected_techs %}
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="name" name="{{tech.id}}">{{tech.name}}</span>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think this should solve your problem. 
Just remember to add

Edit 1:

Try this

```
{% with selected_techs=[] %}
<div class="card-body" id="team-list">                   
   <p class="card-text">Select today's teammates:</p>
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      {% for tech in techs %}
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="name" name="{{tech.id}}">{{tech.name}}</span>
            <span class="move" onclick="{% selected_techs.append(tech) %}" style="float: right;">Add to the team</span>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div class="card-body" id="selected-list">
  <h3 class="title">You have selected the following teammates for today: </h3>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="list-style-type: none;">
      {% for tech in selected_techs %}
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="name" name="{{tech.id}}">{{tech.name}}</span>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! but how about if the user remove the tech from the selected list? can I do a selected_tech.remove(tech)?

Comment: also, i got an error like that: Could not parse the remainder: '(tech)' from 'selected_techs.append(tech)'

Comment: Hello Dhruv, my error is the following Could not parse the remainder: '(tech)' from 'selected_techs.append(tech)'

Answer (score 0):

I found out my solution. I added a form tag for each of my elements in my template, and removed the ul, replaced it by a hidden input with a value of tech.id, and replaced the spans tags where the user used to click by buttons. Then handled it with the views.py by getting the ids.